# XSLT Attribute Value Incrementation

Tags: c#, xml, vb.net, xslt

I need to auto increment the ID attribute value by 1 for various tags within.
This should be my output. The below code is just an example. how should i approach this while writing XSLT code (xml to xml)

```
<Entity id="1">
   <Address id="1">
      <name>James</name>
   <Address>
   <Address id="2">
      <name>James</name>
   <Address>
</Entity>
<Entity id="2">
   <Address id="3">
      <name>John</name>
   <Address>
   <Address id="4">
      <name>Mark</name>
   <Address>
</Entity>
```

Comment: You really need to show your input XML and be precise about what the "various tags" are. Thanks.

Comment: How about create your objects (with proper id, which you can manage from the code), and then serialize them. There are a lot of questions about xml serialization.

Comment: @TimC basically i am creating my own xml structure getting the values from the input xml in a random manner. Various tags in the sense auto incrementing the id attribute of Entity tag by 1 and also the Address tag(continuously) by 1

Comment: Why XSLT when you have c#?  Easily done with XDocument in c#.

Comment: In addition to presenting the input and desired output, we expect you to present evidence of a good-faith effort to solve the problem yourself.  Among other things, that clarifies the question and speaks to various details that we might otherwise need to ask about, such as which version of XSLT you are targetting.